# A simple Hopf algebra problems

Tags: abstract-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

I have a little question when I read an article. Someone can give me any clue?
Let $\mathrm{H}$ be a Hopf algebra and  $\mathrm{B}$ be a braided bialgebra in Left-left-Yetter-Drinfled-module over $\mathrm{H}$ (I don't know how to type this symbol in Latex).
My question is $\mathcal{P}(\mathrm{B}^o)$(primitive space of finite dual) is a Yetter-Drinfeld-module?
From the context the answer seems positive.
Thank you!

It's done!

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Don't fight TeX and let it use the font it wants. As with most celebrities from the 70s, you have to use gentler ways to get it to do what you want, and strong-arming it is not one of them.

Comment: I have already known how to type the symbol of Yetter-Drinfeld-module--------${H \atop H}\mathcal{Y}\mathcal{D}$

Comment: @Hippo, that's usually entered as `{}^H_H\mathcal{YD}`, which looks like ${}^H_H\mathcal{YD}$.

Comment: It's done!

Thanks everybody!

Comment: @Hippo, you should add an answer here to your own question then :)